# How to route traffic only to specific hosts using sshuttle?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I'm currently using [`sshuttle`](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) to access some VPN-restricted resources, the vanilla version of "route everything" works fine but I'd like to know how to use it to route only traffic to those servers.

I should mention that I'm not familiar with the subnet notation and most networking concepts, it's probably trivial for someone with the background knowledge.

Thank you.

Comment: by the way I couldn't add "sshuttle" as a tag due to my low karma in this forum, if someone wishes to add it I'll appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: If you are configuring VPN and routing components, it's probably in your best interest to learn CIDR notation and other basic concepts, as they're core to everything you'll be doing.

Comment: This question has nearly everything you'll need to know to get started: http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work

Comment: Added sshuttle tag. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started reading [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) and while I still don't fully understand everything involved here, I've found the answer I was looking for.

To only route traffic to a speficic host you should use `<IPv4-address>/32` instead of `0/0` as in the example.

My reasoning was that if `0/0` means "route everything" and `/0` means "all the address is the *host* portion" then to reverse it I should specify the address I want to connect to and also make it entirely the *network* portion which turns out to be `/32` for IPv4.

Comment: Looking at the verbose output of sshuttle, if you specify <hostname>/0, it the software translates that to mean <hostname>/32.  Not that your answer is wrong for networking, generally.